# How can I get my comments restored?

Tags: support

I had this comment exchange on this answer:

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68242/16835

but at some point some of my comments were deleted. Now, another comment refers to one of deleted comment, and then I answer again - but the context is lost since my original comments are missing.

What can/should I do to get them restored? (For now I'm just reposting them)

Comment: Do you just want some info from them or are you expecting the comment-stream itself to be restored?

Comment: @Richard: Well, I can read them in my activity log (so I've just discovered); it's more about restoring the comment stream.

Comment: Then no. Comments aren't intended to be permanent.they can be deleted by a mod for any reason and none.

Comment: Ok, please make that an answer which I can accept.

Comment: "(For now I'm just reposting them)" Don't. They were deleted for a reason.

Comment: @phantom42: But I don't know what the supposed reason is, and if it's what I suspect it might be, I have issue with that reason and hence with the deletion. Also, deleting one side of a conversation thread, while the other side refers to it, is an offensive action which is emotionally difficult to accept regardless of the reason.

Comment: You need to give up on the notion that comments are a conversation thread. They are not. They are a technique to provide feedback to improve a question or answer. They get deleted for any reason, or no reason, at moderator whim.

Comment: Kevin gave you a reason below, but even if he hadn't it'd be pretty safe to assume that it was deleted because it was too chatty and devolving off-topic. If you want to have a conversation that isn't directly relevant to the content of the question/answer, open a chat room.

Comment: If replies to your deleted comments still exist and have no context, then you can flag them as obsolete.

Comment: @CreationEdge: Ah, but I don't think they're obsolete... it's the deletion I have a problem with :-)

Comment: Related: [Can I please get the deleted comments made on this question? \[closed\]](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5289/21267).

Answer (score 6):

If the comments that are left on that answer are indicative of the ones that were deleted, I doubt there's any chance of them coming back.

Comments are meant to provide feedback to improve questions and answers. They are intended to be temporary and fleeting. There is a *very* low bar for deleting comments, and once they are gone, that's it.

If they were deleted in the first place, it's likely because someone found them to be unrelated to the purpose of improving the answer; for example, the current thread has devolved into discussion of the legal intricacies of murder in different jurisdiction. I wouldn't be surprised if they got deleted *again*.

Comment: Actually, the deleted comments were much more relevant to the question, and it's the rest of the thread - which devloved etc. etc. - which remains intact.

Comment: For reference, the entire comment stream is extremely likely to get zapped

Comment: @einpoklum Actually, your deleted comment was what caused the thread to devolve.

Comment: @Kevin: I had 2 deleted comments. Also, again, if the devolution was the problem, the 'devolved' comments would have been deleted also. Finally, I could make the argument that it's the answer that causes my comment, causing in turn the 'devolved' thread...

Comment: @einpoklum you had only one comment deleted before you posted this question, and it was reasonably inflammatory. And most likely, I just saw the comment and deleted it from the mod queue without looking over the rest of them

Comment: @Kevin: 2 or 3 comments, actually. Only one of them might be considered inflamattory, and even then  - it's inflammatory in Tolkien's universe, not in ours. it's a heated discussion about fictional entities...

Comment: @einpoklum Moderators can see deleted comments. I assure you, my counting skills are better than your memory of events almost a year ago. You had one deleted comment and two not deleted when you posted this question. Since then, you posted and self-deleted two and I purged all the remaining comments on that post.